# Single Stacked Bar Chart Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I am struggling to get a single stacked bar chart using matplotlib.

I want to create something like this:
[Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMXv.png)

However, even if I use `df.plot.barh(stacked=True, ax=axes_var, legend=False)` I get two separate bars. My data frame currently looks like this:

```
        Percentage
Female        42.9
Male          57.1
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First transpose one column DataFrame:

```
df.T.plot.barh(stacked=True, legend=False)
```

If 2 or more columns:

```
df[['Percentage']].T.plot.barh(stacked=True, legend=False)
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, in case we have another column named "percentage_2", how do we add its barh to the same chart ?

Comment: @KhaledDELLAL - Use `df[['Percentage','percentage_2']].T.plot.barh(stacked=True, legend=False)`